# How to cut dot in string?

Tags: javascript

I tried to cut dot from string using the following function:

```
function removeSymbols(str){

  console.log(str.length);
  str.replace(/\./g, "");
  return str;
}

var str = " народу.";
```

But it does not cut

Comment: `.replace` *returns* a new string.

Comment: Have you tried putting str.replace(".", "");

Comment: @Dawcars: Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @Dawcars its not a matter of his `.replace()` method being incorrect (it is correct), OP needs to return the new string returned from `.replace()` instead of returning the unchanged string that was originally passed into `removeSymbols()`.

Comment: @Dawcars also, not sure if it matters here, but FYI, `.replace(".", "")` would only replace the first dot...it wouldn't work if there were multiple dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your return statement from

`return str;`

To

`return  str.replace(/\./g, "");`

Answer (score 2):

```js
function removeSymbols(str) {
    console.log(str.length);
    str = str.replace(/\./g, "");
    return str;
}
var str = " народу.";
console.log(removeSymbols(str));
```

Comment: This is technically correct, but I don't think it is necessary to reassign `str` when one could just `return str.replace(/\./g, "")` ... I'll still upvote though since it is the first correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

`replace` doesn't change the original string, it will return a new string that is replaced.